# CSS равномерная прозрачная тень вокруг текста

Tags: css, css3

Подскажите как можно сделать прозрачную тень вокруг текста на подобии вот такой?
[image: Прозрачная закругленная тень]

У меня вышла только без закругления. Если добавляю смягчение, то при добавлении прозрачности видны какие-то неравномерные разводы, а нужно именно четкий контур.

Comment: http://codepen.io/IanH/pen/vEBeRm
вот по такому принципу можешь поиграть с text-shadow

Comment: Не выходит. Там все равно нет главного. Нет закругления тени. Обводку я могу сделать жирную, вот только края острые выходят. А если сглаживать их смягчением то при  прозрачности смотрится убого.